# Fragment parent layout transparent

Tags: android, android-fragments, transparency

I use `circularRevealAnimation` to start one  of Fragments. Here's  its `layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_container"
android:background="@color/red"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   ....

</LinearLayout>

</io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>
```

In my `Fragment` class I trigger `revealAnimation` in `onStart()` method.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // SupportAnimator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(container2, 720, 0, 0, 1386); ->line from onCreateView
    animator.setDuration(500);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.start();
    animator.addListener(new SupportAnimator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart() {
            System.out.println("lol222");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd() {
            System.out.println("end");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat() {

        }
    });
}
```

As you  see, the parent layout  has red color, when its child is white. When I started this `Fragment`  I can see  white circularReveal over the red background, when I want to see such animator over previous fragment. How can I achieve this?

I tried to make `background="@null" and so on, while reading SOF related topics. Nothing helped me. So what is write way to set`Fragment`parent`layout`as`transparent`?

Comment: setAlpha to make transparent?

Comment: @mjstam it makes all layout transparent, so I can see nothing of next Fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can implement using xml like this

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or programatically you can change like this

```
yourview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Like many different ways it makes background white.

Answer (score 1):

There was my fault. My container was `LinearLayout`, not `FrameLayout`. Bacause of that there wasn't `transparency`.